# Best USB hub to match the Thunderbolt display?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware-recommendation, thunderbolt-display

I just got a spanking new Apple Thunderbolt Display to work with my Macbook Air and I'm  loving it. The one thing I'm missing from my iMac is the 4 USB ports at the back (the Thunderbolt display only has 3). I realize I can use the 2 USB ports on the MBA but it's just not very convenient (plus I don't like the idea of a laptop being bogged down by earthly constraints such as a dangling phone charger cable).

I'm looking for a USB hub with the following features:

- good-looking (admittedly subjective)
- can hide behind the display that I'd use to plug in the immobile equipment such as scanner, wireless dongles, etc.
- Ideally, no AC power needed (but I get the feeling I won't be able to be too picky on this one).

Is there hardware out there that meets these requirements? If your answer includes a link please link to manufacturers' sites, not to sales sites, which change more frequently.

Comment: While "shopping questions" are off-topic at Stack Exchange sites, questions asking about what hardware can perform a desired function are very much on-topic. This post seems to fall into the latter category. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the various Mac mini stackable USB hubs - those usually look pretty nice.

If you can't find a hub you like the looks of, you could always hide it:

- A [shelf](http://twelvesouth.com/products/backpack/) that goes on the monitor stand to hide items behind the monitor
- Or you could just tape (or velcro, thanks to @jaberg) the hub to the back of the monitor to keep it out of sight.

Comment: Velcro, or even better the hard plastic Velcro-like material, is great for sticking things behind monitors. I use it for the digital converter boxes on wall-mounted TVs and plan to do so for a future TV/AppleTV installation.